# Deactivate mouseenter event then reactivate once animations have finished

Tags: jquery, html, mouseenter

I have the following code which executes some animations etc. when the user hovers over an element, however if they "enter" and "leave" the element with the mouse rapidly and repeatedly it messes up the animations. How can I deactive the mousenter event and then reactivate it once animations have finished?

```
$(".women .text").on("mouseenter", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $( ".men .intro" ).hide();
            $('.women').delay(300).animate({width:"80%"});  
            $('.men').delay(300).animate({width:"20%"});    
            $('.men').animate({opacity: 0.5}, 500); 
            $('.women').animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
            $( ".women .intro" ).delay(600).fadeIn(300);
        });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the timer to whatever timespan you want

```
var mouseEntered = false;

$(".women .text").on("mouseenter", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            if(mouseEntered == false)
            {
                mouseEntered = true;
                $( ".men .intro" ).hide();
                $('.women').delay(300).animate({width:"80%"});  
                $('.men').delay(300).animate({width:"20%"});    
                $('.men').animate({opacity: 0.5}, 500); 
                $('.women').animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
                $( ".women .intro" ).delay(600).fadeIn(300);
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    mouseEntered = false;
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
```

Comment: cool thanks, does just deactivate it for that set amount of time in the timespan then?

Comment: yep, the line inside the function() that converts the mouseEntered  to false

window.setTimeout(function() {
                    mouseEntered = false;
                }, 1000); is going to be executed 1 second or 1000 miliseconds after this piece of code is executed so only after a second can the animations start over.

Comment: can I not use unbind while a function is performed?